# Removing top whitespace from dialog

Tags: css, material-ui

I have a dialog popup using Material UI where I cannot get rid of the whitespace above the title. I've applied a background colour to the title and content area, but this then left a white margin at the top, which I can't seem to get rid of.

Any idea on how to do this?

[image: White space at top problem]

```
<Dialog
  id="myDialog"
  classes={{ paper: classes.dialog }}
  onClose={handleCloseTagInstructions}
  open={openTagInstructions}
  aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
  fullWidth={true}
>
  <DialogActions>
    <IconButton
      className={classes.customizedButton}
      onClick={handleCloseTagInstructions}
    >
      <CloseIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </DialogActions>
  <DialogTitle id="helper-dialog-title" style={{ backgroundColor: '#eeeeee' }}>
    <Typography variant="h5">White's Semi-Open Files at</Typography>
  </DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent style={{ backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5' }} dividers>
    <Typography variant="h6">White's Strategy</Typography>
    <Typography paragraph="true">Blah</Typography>
    <Typography variant="h6">Black's Strategy</Typography>
    <Typography paragraph="true">???</Typography>
    <Typography variant="h6">Notes</Typography>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Typography paragraph="true">Blah.</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Paper width="5%" id="board3"></Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>;
```

Comment: hi, did my answer below work for you?

Comment: Voted as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the dialog margin
`dialog {  margin-top: -10px !important; }`

here is an example with your code :

```html
<Dialog
  style="margin-top: -10px"
  id="myDialog"
  classes={{ paper: classes.dialog }}
  onClose={handleCloseTagInstructions}
  open={openTagInstructions}
  aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
  fullWidth={true}
>
  <DialogActions>
    <IconButton
      className={classes.customizedButton}
      onClick={handleCloseTagInstructions}
    >
      <CloseIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </DialogActions>
  <DialogTitle id="helper-dialog-title" style={{ backgroundColor: '#eeeeee' }}>
    <Typography variant="h5">White's Semi-Open Files at</Typography>
  </DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent style={{ backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5' }} dividers>
    <Typography variant="h6">White's Strategy</Typography>
    <Typography paragraph="true">Blah</Typography>
    <Typography variant="h6">Black's Strategy</Typography>
    <Typography paragraph="true">???</Typography>
    <Typography variant="h6">Notes</Typography>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Typography paragraph="true">Blah.</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Paper width="5%" id="board3"></Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>;
```